# How to avoid cgroup.subtree_control of a delegated unit being reset on service restart

Tags: linux, systemd, cgroups

In the systemd v250 environment, when I restart the service, the `cgroup.subtree_control` is reset.

If I modify the value of `cgroup.subtree_control`, then when I restart the service, systemd will try to overwrite the value of `cgroup.subtree_control`. For example, if I add a `cpu` controller to subtree_control, systemd will remove it from subtree_control when the service is restarted. If I create a subdirectory at this time, and there are still processes in the subgroup when restarting, the startup will fail. The error is as follows:

```
Control process exited, code=exited, status=219/CGROUP
...
Unit process 543222  (xxx) remains running after unit stoped.
....
```

Which seems to be a failure when rewriting the subtree_control.

---

I want to manage `cgroup.subtree_control` by myself when delegation is turned on.

I hope systemd doesn't modify it, doesn't reset `cgroup.subtree_control` of the delegated service when service is restarted.

---

**Relevant files**

**unit file:**

```
[Unit]
Description=DelegateTest

[Service]
Type=simple
TimeoutSec=60s
KillMode=process
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash /test/start_pre.sh
ExecStart=/bin/bash /test/loader.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Delegate=yes
```

**/test/start_pre.sh:**

```
echo "start_pre"
```

**/test/loader.sh**

```
echo "executing"
CGROUP=$(cat /proc/$$/cgroup)
CGROUP_PATH=/sys/fs/cgroup${CGROUP#*::}
if [[ ! -d ${CGROUP_PATH}/job ]]; then
    mkdir ${CGROUP_PATH}/job
fi
echo $$ > ${CGROUP_PATH}/job/cgroup.procs
echo "+cpu" > ${CGROUP_PATH}/cgroup.subtree_control
ping 127.0.0.1 > /dev/null
```

---

**Steps to reproduce this problem**

1. systemctl start DelegateTest.service
2. systemctl status DelegateTest.service

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/DelegateTest.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-07-21 09:58:31 CST; 1s ago
    Process: 541635 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash /test/start_pre.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 541636 (bash)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 23196)
     Memory: 660.0K
        CPU: 11ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/DelegateTest.service
             └─job
               ├─541636 /bin/bash /test/loader.sh
               └─541639 ping 127.0.0.1
```

3. systemctl stop DelegateTest.service
4. systemctl status DelegateTest.service

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/DelegateTest.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2022-07-21 09:58:36 CST; 981ms ago
    Process: 541635 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash /test/start_pre.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 541636 ExecStart=/bin/bash /test/loader.sh (code=killed, signal=TERM)
    Process: 541644 ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 541636 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 23196)
     Memory: 300.0K
        CPU: 13ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/DelegateTest.service
             └─job
               └─541639 ping 127.0.0.1
```

5. systemctl start DelegateTest.service

```
Job for DelegateTest.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status DelegateTest.service" and "journalctl -xeu DelegateTest.service" for details.
```

6. systemctl status DelegateTest.service

```
× DelegateTest.service - DelegateTest
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/DelegateTest.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-07-21 09:58:53 CST; 1s ago
    Process: 541649 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash /test/start_pre.sh (code=exited, status=219/CGROUP)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 23196)
     Memory: 300.0K
        CPU: 84us
     CGroup: /system.slice/DelegateTest.service
             └─job
               └─541639 ping 127.0.0.1
```

---

Relevant issue:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/24064
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/20026
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/18293
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/9119
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8645
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/18104